Font icons corrupted on my Arch Linux after system update
I am using Arch Linux and pretty much update my system daily. I rarely get into much larger problems, find the cause and resolve them. Friday I did an update and didn't notice that my Konsole font icons broke until today.
I rightly assumed that the problem is the font I am using, so I went into appearance to try and find a font that works. To my surprise, only a couple of fonts did work, the rest only showed question marks or empty squares in the place where the logo of the system should be displayed, the folder/file icon, git information and insert/caps lock info.
Once I changed the font, it worked fine.
Couldn't find the source of the problem.
Any ideas?

You mention Konsole, should we assume you are using KDE? Please [edit] and clarify that. Also tell is if the problem appears in all applications, including terminals, whether you see it if you drop to a tty, in the GRUB or EFI boot screen etc. I haven't hit this yet, but I haven't updated for a few days so I will see if I can reproduce, but telling us the context where you see this would help. Also, while this is 100% on topic and welcome here, you are probably more likely to get help on [unix.se] where more *nix folks hang out.

@terdon No, I am using Gnome. I will edit appropriately.
